# Improving image load speeds

Tags: html, image

A website that I'm currently working on has a number of slideshows.  The issue is that the page loads and then the slideshow loads a second later.  How do I improve loading speeds of the images?  The site is hosted on Amazon.  The url is http://gatehouse75.com to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this:

1. Optimise image sizes. For example, images used on the front banner are 1920x1610. However, most screens are not that large. Use different sizes based on view port (screen size).
2. Reduce image sizes by changing compression and/or using a different format.
3. Preload images when the users visit certain parts of the site. That way when users get to a page with a gallery the images get served from the browser cache.
4. Finally, you can put a "loading" notice while images load if none of the above suggestions help. This is good for usability.

Comment: Nice general answer Mohamad!  With out seeing your code, I'd do all that Mohamad mentions as well define the image height and width in HTML if possible.  This forces the browser to reserve the space and increase load speed.  Also look at caching options, my second load was definitely much faster then the first, so perhaps your already doing this.

Comment: Re screen sizes - would disagree these days - very many monitors are full HD, not to mention tablets. If he goes smaller than that then there'll be upscaling for these screens which will affect the quality greatly.

Comment: However the images (I found one to be nearly 1MB) could be compressed much more for little lost of quality.

Comment: @JonEgerton However his question is about increasing speed, not quality, there are always trade offs.

Comment: Instead of a loading notice you could also first use a smaller version of the image that's stretches out to the eventual size and replace it afterwards. Also, interlacing can be an option(no idea about actual browser support).

Comment: @Jon Egerton, I suggested he uses different sizes based on view port, not down size all his images. This should not be a problem for larger screens; the site would use the correct image.

Comment: @defaultNINJA: Looking at the site and the types of images, quality is clearly a major consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your jpgs to lower quality and your logo (in png) to gif in grayscale. This should save a lot of space.

Answer (score 0):

Right now the home page slideshow images are scaled to 1349 X 429 for me. I am using a laptop.  The actual size of the images on the server is 1920 X 610 (at least the one that I inspected). This means two things: (1)The image served is a larger filesize than need be which takes bandwidth, and (2)that the served image needs to get scaled down which takes client time.

What is the max width for this slideshow? It is a fullscreen slideshow, so I understand why the chose to use the bigger image. Though maybe you can take the original compress and resize in a way that is acceptable?

You can also consider having a loading .gif in place while the content loads.

Also, go through and minify linked files... css, js.

Comment: Yes its a full screen slideshow which is why we use the high resolution images.

Answer (score 0):

---

**1.** Follow image file optimization best practices.

**2.** Use a fast CDN combined with a smart caching strategy.

**3**. Put your above-the-fold image refs (especially large "hero" images) in an inline stylesheet, immediately inside the `<head>` tag, in the html element selector, like this:

`<head>
<style> html { background: url(/hero.jpg) no-repeat -9999px -9999px; }
</style>`

This will get you **the fastest time-to-visible** for the images that impact perceived page speed the most.